# html/jsp - The image on my website won't change when replaced in the folder

Tags: html, css, jsp

I'm very new to frontend development, so please understand some inconveniences.

I'm working on my first website, and I seem to have a problem with the images. I downloaded an html template from the internet and used its original images, html, and css files. I wanted to include a logo of my own, so I deleted the original .png file and replaced it with my own, and changed the name so that it could take its place (ex: I changed the name of the file to logo.png when replacing logo.png).

```
<img alt="" src="assets/images/logo-small.png">
```

This is the original code, and I didn't touch anything but the file in the folder itself. Can anyone please tell me what the problem is? I'm sorry if I wasn't specific enough, I will clarify any ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a image folder in your project like in the picture, you'll need to write:

```
 <img alt="" src="./images/random.png">
```

I hope that helps!
Cheers.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I revised the code as you said, but it's still not changing even when I restarted the server... what else do you think could cause this problem?

Comment: @CSM Can you take a print screen of your the folder's area?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but could you specify on how to take a print screen? Do you mean to take a screenshot of the folder structure?

Comment: Don't worry! I mean a screenshoot the same way I posted. You know where you have your index.html, images folder (in the code editor).

Comment: I can't upload images since I have only 1 reputation, but here's an imgur link: https://imgur.com/a/UdjzmEK

Comment: I'm not being able to load the image. 
Take a look at this link, it might solve your problem : [link] (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I think there's something more complicated related to this problem that I can't quite convey through these comments... I'll try to solve this somehow. Thank you so much again!!